# Centering fancybox with position:aboslute not letting me change location

Tags: asp.net, css, fancybox

I have a fancybox that pops up when I click on a link. It opens up somewhere around the center area, however not quite in the middle. The css for the fancybox is:

```
#fancybox-wrap {
    position:absolute;
    /*padding: 20px;*/
    z-index: 1101;
    outline: none;
    display: none;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
```

However, when I have `position:absolute;`, the margin settings become void. Nothing seems to work. `left: 50px;`, etc won't work. Any ideas?

When I change absolute to relative the fancybox is perfectly in the middle where I want it, but it draws the fancybox almost out of view at the bottom.

Comment: Sort of irrelevant, but also important to note: PLEASE don't overuse outline:none in your stylesheets, as it's really important for accessibility reasons. http://outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are positioning something absolutely, you are telling the browser exactly where you want it drawn based on top/bottom and left/right attributes.

To absolutely position in the center of the screen:

```
#fancybox-wrap {
    position:absolute; /* want it positioned absolutely relative to parent */
    width:500px;       /* fixed width of 500px */
    top:50px;          /* 50px down from the top of the screen */
    left:50%;          /* positioned in the middle of the screen */
    margin-left:-250px;/* use a negative margin of half the fixed width */
}
```

Comment: it seems as though the popup is using the websites css for some reason. it aligned the popup's top left corner with the websites top left corner.

Comment: So this style isn't in the site's CSS? Where are you defining it?

Comment: this is what is baffling me. the css I posted is suppose to do the job, I mean when I take out the position it affects it. But for some reason the position specifics just aren't being used.

Comment: Can you use developer tools plugin or FireBug to view the rendered source in FireFox or Chrome? Fancybox may be setting the left and top position on the element. If the css is set directly on a tag, it overrides whatever is provided in the CSS.

Comment: If that is the case, you'll have to modify the FancyBox script instead of the CSS.